# phonegap notification methods still use webview alert

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I'm using phonegap CLI to check if default notifications work. I already added the notification plugin and I got this output when I ran :

> D:\PhoneGap\apps\alerttest>    cordova plugins ls
>
> ['org.apache.cordova.dialogs', 'org.apache.cordova.vibration' ]

This is how my JS looks like:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    if (navigator.notification) {
        //Im trying to overwrite the default alert & confirm here if navigator.notification is defined 
        window.alert = function (title, message, button, onFinish) {
            navigator.notification.alert(message, onFinish, title, button);
        };

        window.confirm = function (title, message, buttons, onFinish) {
            var onDone = function (btnIndex) {
                switch (btnIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        onFinish(true);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        onFinish(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
            navigator.notification.confirm(message, onDone, title, buttons);
        }
    }
    else {
        var $alertBox = $(".alert-box.warning");
        $alertBox.html("No notification support :(");
        $alertBox.show();
    }
});
```

When I use these functions,

```
alert("Alert", "I was clicked.", "Yes, I got it!", null);
confirm("Confirm", "2 + 2 = 4. Yes or no?", ["Yes", "No"], onDone);
```

I get something like these :

[image: for alert][image]

Which is still the WebView alert. I was expecting something like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Using PhoneGap CLI, version number : 3.1.0-0.2.0

Also, Im using Android Jellybean (4.1.2) to check this feature

Comment: which theme u have selected while creating the project ??

Comment: Theme? What theme? Can you provide some links to back what you've typed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I got it! I had to change the `android:theme` in the manifest file from "@*android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" to "@*android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" to viola, it works! Thanks <kbd>Divesh Salian</kbd> for giving me a clue about this!

Comment: am glad that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

make sure this is in your config.xml -

```
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
```

Comment: yes its there. i found it in both ../www/ & ../platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml